# Prestige transferring from Modern Warfare 1 & 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

One of my friends told me that you get special unlocks in Modern Warfare 3 if you went prestige in the first two.

Is this true? If so what sort of unlocks are we talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern Warfare 3 features the Prestige Shop.  Prestige you've performed in a previous Call of Duty games (MW1, World at War, MW2, Black Ops) earns you a single prestige token per game.

Prestige tokens can be spent in the shop to unlock things like an additional custom classes, special emblems and titles, and numerous other features.

Full list (from [here](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige_Shop)):

- Extra custom class (up to 5 extra classes for a total of 10 max)
- Double XP (2 hours in-game time)
- Double weapon XP (2 hours in-game time)
- Regular Package (Callsign Title and Emblem available to those with an extra token     lying around)[2]
- Unlock Gear (can be weapons, equipment, perks)(Available at 1st Prestige)
- Hardened Package (Callsign Titles and Emblems)
- Veteran Package (Callsign Titles and Emblems, unlocked after 10th Prestige)
- Reset All Stats (Availble at 10th Prestige)